# Validate JSON-LD document

Tags: validation, json-ld

Is there a way to validate the incoming json-ld document against its context, so that I can prevent document like this from being saved? **(born supposed to be date)**

```
{
  "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "born": "strstr",
  "name": "John Lennon"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RDF Data Shapes Working Group is [working on a specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/) that will allow you to do that. At the moment there's no officially standardized solution.

Comment: I have just seen your presentation on slideshare **A Deep Dive into JSON-LD and Hydra**. So, can hydra library validate the request that contains json-ld payload?

Comment: Yes, it can. It is based on Symfony and can thus use all the validation goodies it supports.